# Deleting a LinkedIn account where I no longer have access to email address

Tags: linkedin

I created a LinkedIn account using email address created by my employer (the company used G Suite for emails). I no longer work for the employer, and hence no longer have access to the email address.

I wish to delete the said LinkedIn account as that's not my primary (personal) account. It also shows up prominently in Google searches.

What are my possible options to get that account deleted (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [LinkedIn Help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/slideshare/answer/1501/no-access-to-email-address?lang=en)

> There are instances when you no longer use or have access to the email address used to register your LinkedIn account. LinkedIn suggests first trying to sign in with a secondary email address that's associated with your account. LinkedIn allows you to sign in with any email address associated with your account.
>
> #### **If you still can't access your account:**
>
> If you haven't been able to recover your password or don't have access to an email address associated with your account, LinkedIn can help by verifying your identity. To do this, LinkedIn uses a technology that processes encrypted scans of your government-issued ID so that LinkedIn can help get you back into your account as quickly and securely as possible.
>
> [LinkedIn only] uses the ID information you provide to verify who you are, and [LinkedIn] only holds onto it for a short period of time while your account issues are being resolved. Generally, scans and any associated personal information are permanently deleted within **14** days.
>
> To get started, you'll need:
>
> - A smartphone or a computer with a webcam.
> - Your driver license, state-issued ID card, or passport.
> - An email address where LinkedIn can reach you.
> - Access to a desktop computer.
>
> Follow the steps below on desktop:
>
> - Once you begin the identity verification process, you'll be asked to take a photo of your ID with your smartphone or webcam.
>
>   - Enter the email address associated with your account so that we can locate your account, and follow the onscreen instructions.
>   - On the following page, click **I don't have access to my email address**. First, LinkedIn asks you for a new email address. Next, LinkedIn asks you to provide a valid passport or government ID.
>   - After you're finished, LinkedIn processes your information and be in contact to assist you further.
>
> **[Follow this link to verify your identity.](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/request-password-reset)**
>
> **Note:** If you only have one email address and it has bounced, you will not be able to send a confirmation link to yourself. You will have to verify your identity to regain access to your account.

---

#### Closing account:

Once you regained access to your account you can use this link to close your account instantly: 
**[https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/closeaccountnow](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/68889)**

From [LinkedIn Help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/63/closing-your-linkedin-account?lang=en)

> To close your LinkedIn account from the **Settings & Privacy** page:
>
> - Click the  **Me** icon at top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> - Select **Settings & Privacy** from the drop-down.
> - Under the **Account management** section of the **Account** tab, click **Change** next to **Closing your LinkedIn account**
> - Check the reason for closing your account and click **Next**.
> - Enter your account password and click **Close account**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find the instructions to be helpful and followed them. However, I hit a roadblock and can use your expert advise. When asked to provide a new email address, I entered my primary email address (with which I already have an account on LinkedIn). Following the mentioned steps, I was presented with an error that `someone else is already using that email address`. This clearly implies I need a email address unassociated with LinkedIn to recover the account that needs to be deleted. Am I right? What course of action should I take?

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes, you are right. you need non-linkedin-associated email address

Comment: This text is taken verbatim from the LinkedIn help pages. You should quote the text that's not your own and provide a link to the source. Otherwise, this is plagiarism.

Comment: @Nimesh: That's not quoting the referenced material. My point was that the "quote" feature of the editor should be used to distinguish the author's actual words vs. the ones copied from elsewhere. Answers should _not_ simply be copied wholesale from elsewhere. I've attempted to fix up the text appropriately.

Comment: Yes, seriously. Stack Exchange takes it seriously, and your changes do not deviate enough from the source text to make it an original work. Plagiarism can get you banned. See [Help: referencing](/help/referencing) and [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/21960).

Comment: @user0 - don't rollback these changes. You **must** acknowledge the source of quoted material.